# Firebase search for users with same username/ database structure

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The structure of my database has users with a username that is created when a user creates an account. The username is under the meta data.  I already have over 2000 users and never thought to restrict usernames/ make sure not duplicates or append numbers when people login with facebook or google (I am currently just using their names in those cases).  I want to be able to search for usernames:

```
  "Users" : {
    "eOhY4Wp6QNUtEjVTdmBff8UDY5p2" : {
      "meta" : {
        "username" : "testName"
      }
    }
  }
```

I figured the only way would be to create another section that lists usernames in reverse:

```
"UserList" : {
        "testName" : "eOhY4Wp6QNUtEjVTdmBff8UDY5p2",
      }
```

But the issue with this is that I can't have multiple users with the same username/ I don't think it's possible to have multiple nodes that have the same key.

Is this the best method to approach this situation?  Or is there an alternative to have the same username (I don't want to pull down the whole users using snapshot since this would be super data intensive).  If this is the best method I was figuring I would go in and manually change the duplicates that are already in the database.

Edited Additional Content:

Here is the only approach I know of to get usernames from first structure would be to get the whole snapshot and then filter for users with the username- this would download the entire snapshot which is super data intensive since I only need the users that have the username that I am searching for:

```
const snapshot = await firebase.child("Users").on("value")
```

I know there is the OrderBy method, but isn't that a top level approach/ wouldn't I need "testName" directly under users rather than 2 layers deeper.

```
    const snapshot = await firebase.child("Users").orderByChild("username")
   .equalTo('testName')
```

Comment: I am having a hard time parsing your question. Keep in mind that "is this the best approach" is seldom a great question, so I'd recommend aiming for "why does my code do abc, while I expected it to do xyz?" Since you shared no code, it is extra hard to help. "I want to be able to search for usernames" What is keeping you from doing that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added on some example code for the only way I know how to pull down the whole user list (which I would then use a map or filter function using javascript).  This is super inefficient.  Is there a way to simple get the users by UID under users without having to pull down the whole Users node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your user name is in a property that is nested under a known path, you can query it like this:

```
firebase.child("Users")
   .orderByChild("meta/username")
   .equalTo('testName')
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this will only pull down Users with testName (I know this is the response I get back), but it won't do a snapshot with other values and then filter.  Not sure exactly how orderByChild works.  From the docs- `Any node which does not have the child key we're querying on is sorted with a value of null`- so if there are a thousand users and it gets null for all non users with testName, would it take much less data to have a separate structure where I can pull directly and there is only 1 option- const snapshot = await firebase.child("UsersList").child("testName").on("value")

Comment: If you store the users grouped by their `username` as a key, you can read all users for a username by a direct lookup and without a query. Data transfer wise there is no difference between the two (as long as you've declared the `.indexOn`). But a spread out data structure scales better, since the database doesn't have to query a long list to find the users with the name. So you're trading some coding convenience (and possible data duplication) for better scalability, which is a common trade-off when using NoSQL databases.